# Form Action Posting null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

My baldness is growing more rapidly than it should be. I first posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209387/ienumerable-is-null-when-i-expect-values) a couple days ago. I now know the problem and have it working... sort of. Another problem surfaced in it's place.

To solve the previous problem, I manually created the name to `requestedDays[{0}].DateOfLeave` where `{0}` was a `Guid`. This allowed my controller to properly receive the List<> of values.

Using [this article's method](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/), the name generated is `requestedDays[{0}].DayRequested.DateOfLeave` which my controller doesn't properly receive because the name has the class in it, `DayRequested.DateOfLeave`.

```
    [Authorize, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(LeaveRequest leaveRequest, List<DayRequested> requestedDays)
    {
    }
```

I have tried to figure out work-arounds with the manual generation, but nothing I have tried works thus far. [You can see my validation method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227438/custom-validation-rules-for-asp-net-mvc2-application). I do know about the [second part of Sanderson's article on validation](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) however, it is quite hard to validate something that isn't being passed into the method.

This is my ViewModel I am using in my partial view.

```
public class LeaveRequestRow
{
    public LeaveRequestRow(DayRequested dayRequested, List<SelectListItem> leaveRequestType)
    {
        this.DayRequested = dayRequested;
        this.LeaveRequestType = leaveRequestType;
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> LeaveRequestType { set; get; }
    public DayRequested DayRequested { set; get; }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed? Should I convert my dropdown to a jQuery build control and stop using the ViewModel?

Comment: I'm thinking the code provided with the article you linked might be buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, though not as elegantly as I had hoped. All `TextBoxFor` had to be changed to `TextBox` along with the addtional changes needed with doing this. The names then were correctly generated and I could move on. This did break the ability for the validation message to appear next to the field, though `ValidationSummary` still does work. I will be working on fixing that later on and post code samples and a solution on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Binding 1-N controller arguments of complex types can be kind of tricky.

Your code examples are not meshing with my fried end of day Friday brain but I'll give it a shot.

Assuming the LeaveRequest class looks like this:

```
public class LeaveRequest {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

The posted form keys must be:

```
leaveRequest.Text
leaveRequset.Number
```

That is the easy part.  The 1-N binding of a list of DayRequested gets a little weird.  Say the DayRequested object looks like this:

```
public class DayRequested  {
    public string Words { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Your posted form keys look like:

```
requestedDays[0].Data
requestedDays[0].Words
requestedDays[1].Data    
requestedDays[1].Words
requestedDays[2].Data    
requestedDays[2].Words
requestedDays[3].Data    
requestedDays[3].Words
```

The default MVC binder should then trun all 10 form values into your two method arguments ... a POCO and a List of POCOs.

Comment: I am confused. My posted keys are `requestedDays[x].Class.Field` right now. I want to change that to `requestedDays[x].Field` without needing to manually rename everything.